# Google Cloud Platform - Is there a way to delete a project?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have created many projects that I will not use any more. How do I delete them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you are looking for: [Create, shut down, and restore projects](https://support.google.com/googleapi/answer/6251787?hl=en#zippy=%2Cshut-down-a-project)

> To shut down a project:
>
> 1. Go to the [API Console](https://console.developers.google.com/).
> 2. Open the console left side menu and select IAM & Admin, then select Settings.
> 3. Find the name or project ID of the project you want to shut down, then click SHUT DOWN. A confirmation screen describing what will
>    happen appears.
> 4. To confirm, enter your project ID and click Shut down.
>
> [...]
>
> After a 30-day waiting period, the project and associated data are permanently deleted from the console.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting a Google Cloud Platform project can also be done through the Cloud Console.

Follow these steps:

1. Go to the [Cloud Resource Manager page](https://console.cloud.google.com/cloud-resource-manager)
2. On the left sidebar, you will see a list of all your Google Cloud projects.
3. Next to the project you want to delete, click on the three vertical
   dots icon. (On the right side)
4. A menu will open. Select "Delete" to delete the project.
5. Confirm the deletion in the popup dialog.

The Cloud Console provides a simple interface to view and manage all your Google Cloud projects in one place.

Please see the attached image. :)

[image]